# Border behind grid line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to show the gridline above the chart but behind the chart border and I didn't found any solution for that.

I used z to show the gridline above the chart and changed the gridline color to the background color. That hides the grid line that outside the chart but I still have an annoying line on the chart border that I don't know how to hide...

here is what I'm talking about:

[image]

My configuration:

```
 this.myChart = new Chart(this.canvasRef.current, {
      type: "line",
      options: {
        title: { display: false },
        legend: { display: false },
        elements: {
          point: {
            radius: 0,
          },
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
            {
              gridLines: {
                drawBorder: false,
                display: true,
                color: "#f8f8f8",
                lineWidth: 1,
                z: 1,
                drawTicks: false,
                zeroLineColor: "#f8f8f8",
              },
            },
          ],
          yAxes: [
            {
              gridLines: {
                drawBorder: false,
                display: false,
              },
              ticks: {
                display: false,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      data: {
        labels: [2.7, 3.7, 5.7, 6.7, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [86, 114, 106, 106, 107, 111, 133],
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(63, 121, 230, 0.4)",
            fill: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    });
```

Comment: Are you using chert.js or a custom plugin?

Comment: I'm using chart.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw your own grid lines directly on to the `canvas` using the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). It offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code. You can use the `afterDraw` hook to draw vertical lines up to individual points contained in the dataset but stop just underneath the line.

```
ctx.lineTo(x, yTop + 2);
```

Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: "line",
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;      
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      ctx.save();
      xAxis.ticks.forEach((value, index) => {
        var x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(index);
        var yTop = yAxis.getPixelForValue(chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[index]);        
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#f8f8f8';
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, yAxis.bottom);
        ctx.lineTo(x, yTop + 2);
        ctx.stroke();        
      });
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: [2.7, 3.7, 5.7, 6.7, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9],
    datasets: [{
      data: [86, 114, 106, 106, 107, 111, 133],
      borderColor: "#3e95cd",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(63, 121, 230, 0.4)",
      fill: true
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawBorder: false,
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you! It's working... how can I define the line width?
And how can I show the hover line (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159895/moving-vertical-line-when-hovering-over-the-chart-using-chart-js) above the line I draw?

Comment: @ronara: You can define the width of the grid line through `ctx.lineWidth`. I just updated the code and defined `ctx.lineWidth = 2;` in order to show how it works. Regarding the hover line, this is a complete new issue that needs further investigation. Please give it a try and post a new question for this new issue in case you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Use `borderWidth: 0` inside the datasets as the following.

```js
...
datasets: [
  {
    data: [86, 114, 106, 106, 107, 111, 133],
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(63, 121, 230, 0.4)",
    fill: true,
  },
],
...
```