# ChartJS - Moving vertical line is display on top of tooltip

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

[image]

Hello,

I've followed this post ([Moving vertical line when hovering over the chart using chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159895/moving-vertical-line-when-hovering-over-the-chart-using-chart-js)) to draw a vertical line on my chart.

With a single dataset, it's working just fine.

But for a multiple datasets display (with stacked options on the y-axis), the vertical line is drawn over the chart's tooltip.

Neither setting the z-index of the chart's tooltip nor the vertical line could solve my problem. Since I can't find any property to do that.

Do you have any idea/suggestion to solve this issue?

I'm using react-chart-js 2 with chart-js ^2.9.4 as a peer dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom plugin that draws after all the datasets have drawn but before the tooltip is drawn:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    },
    plugins: {
      customLine: {
        width: 5,
        color: 'pink'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'customLine',
    afterDatasetsDraw: (chart, x, opts) => {
      const width = opts.width || 1;
      const color = opts.color || 'black'

      if (!chart.active || chart.active.length === 0) {
        return;
      }

      const {
        chartArea: {
          top,
          bottom
        }
      } = chart;
      const xValue = chart.active[0]._model.x

      ctx.lineWidth = width;
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(xValue, top);
      ctx.lineTo(xValue, bottom);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The afterDatasetDraw hook solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can do with below code also,

```js
insert below code in plugin section

plugins: {
  verticalLine: {
    width: 2,
    color: 'red'
  }
}

plugins: [
  {
    id: 'verticalLine',
    afterEvent: (chart, args, pluginOptions) => {
      const width = pluginOptions.width || 1;
      const color = pluginOptions.color || 'black';
      const {
        ctx,
        chartArea: { top, bottom }
      } = chart;
      ctx.lineWidth = width;
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(chart.tooltip.caretX, top);
      ctx.lineTo(chart.tooltip.caretX, bottom);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
]
```